# Чтение пустых строк из файла с помощью cmd/bat

Tags: cmd, bat

Добрый день. Мне необходимо считать некоторую часть из файла с помощью *cmd*, а затем записать ее в другой файл. Например начальный файл *in.txt* выглядит так:

> #beg
>      line 1
>
> line 3
>      #end
>      #comment
>      text ...

Пусть нужно выделить и записать только ту часть, которая находится между #beg и #end. Это можно сделать следующим образом:

```
@echo off
@set d=0
@setlocal ENABLEDELAYEDEXPANSION
@del out.txt
@for /f "usebackq tokens=*" %%i in (in.txt) do (
    @set l=%%i
    @set sl=!l:~0,4!
    if "#end" == "!sl!" (@set d=0)
    if !d!==1 (@echo %%i>>out.txt)
    if "#beg" == "!sl!" (@set d=1)
)
@endlocal
```

В результате будет запиан файл *out.txt* следующего вида:

> line 1
>      line 3

При этом пустая строка разделяющая *line 1* и *line 3* потеряется и не запишется в *out.txt*. И собственно вопрос. Каким образом читать и записывать текст построчно с учетом пустых строк?

Comment: echo. явлется переходом каретки, надеюсь это наведет на мысль

Comment: да, @PavelBereznichenko, я знаю об этом. Пустую строку можно записать использовав `ehco.>>file.txt`. Но вопрос касается чтения пустых строк, а не записи.

Comment: Исходя из того как нужно выводить пустую строку (как уже верно отметил Пауло), следует, что лучше заменить Вашу команду **@echo %%i>>out.txt** на  **@echo.%%i>>out.txt**. Если значение переменной будет пустое, то в выходной фал просто добавится пустая строка. Как, собственно, и реализовано в ответе, предложенным мною.

Answer (score 1):

Да можно "тупо" искать текст до строки "**#end**", перенаправляя найденное в выходной файл.

```
@setlocal enableextensions enabledelayedexpansion
@del out.txt
@for /f "skip=1 delims=: tokens=1*" %%i in ('findstr /n /r ".*" in.txt') do (
@set str=%%j
if "!str!"=="#end" goto end
@echo.!str!>>out.txt
)
@endlocal
:end
```

Comment: Исходя из описанных начальных условий, считаем что нам не нужна первая строка: **skip=1**

Comment: Добрый день. Спасибо за ответ. Это решает проблему. Логично, что если не удается записать перенос строки один раз - можно записывать его всегда. Но я до сих пор не могу понять каким образом с помощью команд cmd отыскать пустую строку во время чтения.

Comment: Как записать пустую строку Вам уже ответили. А вот как определить является ли переменная пустой? Просто используя сравнение конструкцией if. Например, **if "%l%"=="" @echo Пустое значение**. Также временами можно использовать в операторе проверку на существование переменной, конструкция **if defined variable**